# Web API 2 looks for get when using ajax post?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I have this AJAX call:

```
 let errorModel = {
            exception: exception,
            extraMessage: extraMessage,
            time: Date.now()
        }
            $.ajax({
            url: "/api/error/LogError",
            type: "POST",
            data: errorModel
        });
```

And this web api 2 method here in this controller

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/Error")]
public class ErrorController : ApiController
{

[HttpPost]
    [Route("LogError")]
    public IHttpActionResult LogError([FromBody]ErrorModel errorModel)
    {

        try
        {
            _db.ErrorModels.Add(errorModel);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + errorModel.Id), errorModel);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
        }
}
```

But when my code reaches the ajax call, I get an error message like this:

```
{
  "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have plenty of api calls like this, and all of them work.

Comment: something somewhere is sending a GET. Maybe there's a form and you didn't prevent the default submission, or something? Clearly the code you posted is not responsible, but something else is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by an unrelated problem in the code (see self-answer).

Comment: `type` is the wrong field IIRC. Anyway, you can use `$.post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all sorry for taking your time it seems it was a stupid error on my side, it seems my javascript Date.Now() wasn't returning what i expected and the api method received it as 00/00/0001 which was denied by the SQL server.
Am not sure why the error message was saying what it was but after i fixed that by setting datetime in the api call the error resolved it self.
Thanks all for your time

Comment: when you use REST API's never trust client application. You could have taken date time from c# itself i.e. if you are not taking the time from user. But taking time at the call of API. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code and found it working fine.

The error message you posted seems indicate that you are using 'get' method in ajax instead of 'post' method.

I have found the result from popular REST-client 'postman'.

Note: I have used string data-type for all of the properties of ErrorModel

[image]